# Apply function to variable subset of columns

Tags: r, apply

Consider this toy data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2),
             meandoy = c(3,2),
             temp199701 = c(4,2),
             temp199702 = c(15,10),
             temp199703 = c(-3,7),
             temp199704 = c(-1,6),
             temp199801 = c(1,5),
             temp199802 = c(9,10),
             temp199803 = c(-2,2),
             temp199804 = c(-5,11))
```

I want to add a new column with the result of a function for each year and each row. In other words, each new `GDDyear`column gets the value of calculating from `tempyear01`to `tempyear04`.

I can achieve it with this:

```
sum.GDD <- function(x) sum(x[x > 5]-5, na.rm = TRUE)
    
yearlist <- c(1997, 1998)
        
for (year in yearlist){
      text <- paste("GDD",toString(year), sep = "")
      df[[text]] <- df %>%  #store result in this vector
        dplyr::select(contains(toString(year))) %>% #take variables that have year
        apply(1, sum.GDD) #calculate GDD5 across those variables
    }
```

But there is a twist. I want to apply the function only to the number of columns specified in `meandoy` each year.

For example, `GDD1997` in the first row will be the result of calculating the first 3 columns starting from `temp199701`, because `meandoy = 3`. `GDD1998` will get the result from `temp199801`, `temp199802` and `temp199803`.

In the second row the `meandoy = 2` so the result of `GDD1997` will be calculated from `temp199701` and `temp199702`. `GDD1998` from `temp199801` and `temp199802`.

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt a problem is usually made simpler by turning the data into a long format.

Since you're already using `dplyr` we can:

```
totals <- df %>%
  # Turn the dataframe into format id, meandoy, year, doy, value by parsing
  # the columns while unpivoting.
  pivot_longer(
    c(everything(), -id, -meandoy), 
    names_to = c("year", "doy"), names_pattern = "temp(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", 
    names_transform = list(year = as.integer, doy = as.integer)
  ) %>%
  # Selects all columns (in the original df) from year01 to year<meandoy>.
  filter(doy <= meandoy) %>%
  # Calculate the GDD  
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  summarize(total = sum.GDD(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  # Back to the original format.
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = total, names_prefix = "GDD") 
  # Selects all columns (in the original df) from year01 to year<meandoy>.
  filter(doy <= meandoy) %>%
  # Calculate the GDD  
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  summarize(total = sum.GDD(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  # Back to the original format.
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = total, names_prefix = "GDD") 

left_join(df, totals, by = "id")
```

This should be faster than an approach doing row-wise operations and/or loops.

Comment: Just a comment, the `mutate(...)` step can be done by the `pivot_longer()` in the previous step if you change it to `pivot_longer(c(everything(), -id, -meandoy), names_to = c("year", "doy"), names_pattern = "temp(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", names_transform = list(year = as.integer, doy = as.integer))`. It's a little different because it doesn't retain the `name` column, but the final product is the same.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was only looking at `sep`. This also makes the extraction of the year safer, thanks!

Comment: Yes thanks, the only thing is that doy is now the last part of a temp199701. In the real data, it should be a consecutive number from 1 to meandoy. That's because the real dataset is much longer with many days and months. Therefore, meandoy can contain a value of, say, 110.

Comment: As long as it clearly follows the same structure you can just adapt the regex, e.g. `"temp(\\d{4})(\\d+)"`

Comment: That didn't work but I fixed it by adding a new line between pivot_longer and the filter: ```group_by(id, meandoy, year) %>% mutate(pos = 1:n() ) %>% ```. This way, I get the consecutive number I wanted from 1 to 365 (end of each year in the original data). Anyway, thanks for your approach. I got stuck trying to edit the original loop and the apply function which probably was not a good idea.